# Правильно ли внутри VM хранить UserControl?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

У меня есть главная `VM` которая хранит 2 `UserControl` и `VM-ки` к ним. Смена `UserControl` происходит благодаря свойству `CurrentUserControl` которое привязывается к вьюшке. Насколько правильно хранить `UserControl` внутри `ViewModel` и как лучше это делать со стороны архитектуры `MVVM`?

Также для смены одного `UserControl` на другой я в каждую `VM-ку` передаю ссылку на главную `VM` и она через эту ссылку их меняет. В правильности этого решения я тоже сомневаюсь.

```
public class MainVm : VmBase
{
    public MainVm()
    {
        LoginAndRegisterVm = new LoginAndRegisterVm(this);
        EnterRegistrationKeyVm = new EnterRegistrationKeyVm(this);
        EnterRegistrationKeyUserControl = new EnterRegistrationKey();
        EnterRegistrationKeyUserControl.DataContext = EnterRegistrationKeyVm;
        LoginUserControl.DataContext = LoginAndRegisterVm;
        CurrentUserControl = LoginUserControl;
    }
    public LoginAndRegisterVm LoginAndRegisterVm { get; set; }
    public EnterRegistrationKeyVm EnterRegistrationKeyVm { get; set; }
    public UserControl LoginUserControl { get; set; } = new LoginPage();
    public UserControl EnterRegistrationKeyUserControl { get; set; }

    private UserControl _currentUserControl;
    public UserControl CurrentUserControl
    {
        get { return _currentUserControl; }
        set { _currentUserControl = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

Часть `Xaml` :

```
<UserControl Grid.Row="1"
             Content="{Binding CurrentUserControl}" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С точки зрения MVVM — нет. VM вовсе не должна знать и иметь представление о View, о том, показана ли данная VM в данный момент на экране, и если да, то как и во скольких местах.

---

Думаю, что правильный паттерн для вашего случая такой:

1. Вы заводите две вложенные VM: для вашего случая это, судя по всему, `LoginAndRegisterVm` и `EnterRegistrationKeyVm`.
2. Заводите в `MainVm` свойство `CurrentPart` типа `VmBase`. В него кладите `LoginAndRegisterVm` или `EnterRegistrationKeyVm`, как вам нужно .
3. Во View прописываете привязки:

   ```
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:EnterRegistrationKeyVm}">
       <!-- здесь контент для отображения EnterRegistrationKeyVm, например просто: -->
       <view:EnterRegistrationKeyUserControl/>
   </DataTemplate>

   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginAndRegisterVm}">
       <view:LoginUserControl/>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```
4. В основном XAML пишете просто

   ```
   <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentPart}"/>
   ```

Привязка `DataContext` по идее произойдёт автоматически.

---

Вопрос правильности изменения одного VM-объекта другим не регулируется MVVM. Применяйте тот паттерн, который вам кажется более правильным.

Comment: Для того чтобы сделать многостраничное приложение нужно cменять один `UserControl` на другой. Где тогда должны храниться  `UserControl` если не в `VM` и кто должен управлять их сменой?

Comment: @Lightness: Дополнил ответ. `UserControl`'ы должны быть однозначно во View.

Comment: `VmBase` просто реализует `INPC`. Если в нее записать `VM` разве контрол сможет увидеть свойства которые сидят в ней? Или это произойдет благодаря `DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginAndRegisterVm}"`?

Comment: @Lightness: Да, WPF смотрит на runtime-тип. Как, вы думаете, работает `Binding` к свойствам `DataContext`, ведь свойство `DataContext` имеет тип `object`?

Comment: Действительно, не подумал об этом. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста!

Comment: А можно как-то в `xaml` отловить смену `UserControl`, чтобы анимировать смену контролов или сделать плавное появление нового контрола?

Comment: @Lightness: Это уже отдельный вопрос. (Кстати, когда-то такой был, но на него, кажется, не ответили.)